# Spring boot oauth application not redirecting to the login.html after successful logout

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I have followed [Spring Boot and OAuth2](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_logout) tutorial and done some of the changes for the UI as below.

Created a **login.html** with below content

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
     <title>Demo</title>
     <meta name="description" content="" />
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <h1>Login</h1>
     <div class="container unauthenticated">
         <div class="container unauthenticated">
              With Google: <a href="/login">click here</a>
         </div>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And in the **index.html** I have removed the below piece of code

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<div class="container unauthenticated">
    <div class="container unauthenticated">
        With Google: <a href="/login">click here</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have also provided the Google **clientId** and **clientSecret** in the **application.yml**.

And changed in the **configure** implementation as below

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("/**")
           .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login**", "/webjars/**")
           .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
           .authenticated()
        .and()
           .exceptionHandling()
           .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login.html"))
        .and()
           .logout()
           .logoutSuccessUrl("/login.html")
           .permitAll()
        .and()
           .csrf() 
         .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
}
```

I can signin and logout properly. ***But after logout its not redirecting to the login.html***. I can see one request will go to login.html but browser will not refresh. If I refresh the browser mannually it will go the login.html page.

**How can I redirect to login.html after successful logout from the application.**